# Phonegap redirect no esta funcionando

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, framework7

Soy medio nuevo en esto, es la primera vez que utilizo framework7, vi la documentacion, y que tenia que usar el router de framework7 pero al parecer este no funciona, alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo funcionar?

```js
// Initialize app
var myApp = new Framework7();


// If we need to use custom DOM library, let's save it to $$ variable:
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add view
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Because we want to use dynamic navbar, we need to enable it for this view:
    dynamicNavbar: true
});

// Handle Cordova Device Ready Event
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {

});


// Now we need to run the code that will be executed only for About page.

// Option 1. Using page callback for page (for "about" page in this case) (recommended way):
myApp.onPageInit('about', function (page) {
    // Do something here for "about" page

})

// Option 2. Using one 'pageInit' event handler for all pages:
$$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
    // Get page data from event data
    var page = e.detail.page;

    if (page.name === 'about') {
        // Following code will be executed for page with data-page attribute equal to "about"
        myApp.alert('Here comes About page');
    }
})

$$(document).on("click", "#glog", function() {
  window.plugins.googleplus.login(
      {},
      function (obj) {
        localStorage.setItem('email', obj.email);
        myApp.alert(obj.email);
      },
      function (msg) {
        myApp.alert(msg);
      }
  );
 });

// Option 2. Using live 'pageInit' event handlers for each page
$$(document).on('pageInit', '.page[data-page="index"]', function (e) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('email')) {
    myApp.alert('go to login');
  }
})

$$(document).on('pageInit', '.page[data-page="login"]', function (e) {
  mainView.router.load({url:'index.html'});
    if (localStorage.getItem('email')) {
      mainView.router.loadPage({url:'index.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true })
    }
})

$$(document).on('pageInit', '.page[data-page="logout"]', function (e) {
    myApp.alert('go to login');
})
```

Lo estoy usando para el login, como veran. Los alert funcionan bien osea que a la funcion se esta entrando pero el router no funciona, cabe aclarar que tampoco muestra ningun error en consola, solo no hace nada. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Buenas, perdona que me meta, no hay forma de que uses otro `framework`, solo pregunto ya que existen una soluciones un poco mejores al momento del desarrollo móvil híbrido.

Comment: Me gustaria ver otros, cual me recomiendas?

Comment: Yo se mas en react-native y lo estoy intentado usar pero fua errores por todos lados, cada vez que intento hacer algo, ahora intento ponerle el google login con expo y me tira uri_mismatch

Comment: Bueno, en lo personal, pienso que quizás el error sea que estas haciendo las cosas un poco apresurado, primero quiero saber si has programado antes en react-native, pero sin la ayuda de expo, si no por fuera, y la otra, es, que si has desarrollado usando angular?

Comment: No se angular, si se usar react, una vez intente react-native sin expo y salio todo bastante bien pero esta vez no. Uso el create-react-native-app y no se  esa como cambiada, no me mustra como escuchar la aplicacion del metro bundler, si la abro en xcode con simulator cuando cambio algo falla o si instalo un paquete npm parece como si se desinstalaran los demas

Comment: mmm, ya veo, has buscado videos de explicación a ver que tal, voy a ver si consigo unos videos al respecto.